# Specific Order by Clause Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Let say I have grocery shop with 2 type of customer `Regular - R` and 'Corporate - C` with them i have an agreement of prices based on dates. Sample data would look like.

```
Type(C/R)   CustID  From Date   Cost
C                   1/11/2017   10
C              1    1/11/2017   12
                    1/11/2017   14
R                   1/11/2017   9
C              1    10/11/2017  11
C                   11/11/2017  15
```

From the table you can see `Type`,`Custid` are not mandatory. My rate picker matches max matching columns from input based on from date to give me cost to apply.

Sample Input:(Input will always have type,custid and from date)

`Case 1: Type - c,Cust ID - 1, dealdate(fromdate) - 2/11/2017`

**Output:** `Row number 2 with price 12`

`Case 2: Type - C, Cust ID - 2,dealdate(fromdate) - 2/11/2017`

**Output:** `Row number 1 with price 10`

`Case 3: Type - C, Cust ID - 2,dealdate(fromdate) - 12/11/2017`

**Output:** `Row number 6 with price 15`

My output will match max matching column first and then will check for valid date it means matching columns have high priority than from date(but yes it has to be valid period).

**My Approach:**

```
select * from (
select row_number() over(partition by partition_column order by
from_date desc,type,custid) rn,a.* from (
select *,'1' as partition_column from rate 
where from_date <= :d_date and (type = :type or type is null) and 
(custid = :custid or custid is null)) a) where rn=1;
```

I am not getting the desired result. Can anyone help please.

Comment: is CUST ID = 2 missing in your sample data?

Comment: no cust id = 2 is not missing which means i don't have any special agreement with cust id 2 then row number 1 will be picked with price 10. Null symbolize that it can be used for anyone. but with a value signifies for that particular person only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what you want.

```
create table rate(
   type      varchar2(5)
  ,cust_id   number
  ,from_date date not null
  ,cost      number not null
);

insert into rate(type, cust_id, from_date, cost) values('C',  null, date '2017-11-01', 10);
insert into rate(type, cust_id, from_date, cost) values('C',  1,    date '2017-11-01', 12);
insert into rate(type, cust_id, from_date, cost) values(null, null, date '2017-11-01', 14);
insert into rate(type, cust_id, from_date, cost) values('R',  null, date '2017-11-01',  9);
insert into rate(type, cust_id, from_date, cost) values('C',  1,    date '2017-11-10', 11);
insert into rate(type, cust_id, from_date, cost) values('C',  null, date '2017-11-11', 15);
```

This statement works by finding records that match either type or customer. The Date input must be satisfied. In the end, higher priority is given to customer ID than customer type, and in case multiple records come, the one with most recent from date is picked.

```
select type, cust_id, cost, from_date 
  from (select r.*
              ,case when cust_id = 2   then 1 end as cust_id_matches
              ,case when type    = 'C' then 1 end as type_matches
          from rate r
         where (type = 'C' or cust_id = 2)      -- Either attribute my match
           and from_date <= date '2017-11-12'   -- Mandatory, must be valid
         order
            by cust_id_matches asc nulls last   -- Order customer ID matches first
              ,type_matches    asc nulls last   -- Then Matches for type
              ,from_date       desc             -- Pick most recent if multiple records
        )        
 where rownum = 1;
```

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ff9f0/5/0)